# push notification not working in live app when new version uploaded

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I have used push notification in one of my app which is live on app store. It was working fine before some days. But now push notification is not receiving.I uploaded new version of app on app store after this problem occurs.

Both the versions (live and in review) have different push certificates. i have revoked the previous certificate of the app which is live. will this create any problem with the live app?

Comment: for which iOS you created that app?

Comment: i use iOS8 for this.

Answer (score 0):

may be that is due to update of iOS! you have to check for iOS version

for ios 8

```
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

for else

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Comment: i know that but i don't think so this is problem.